# What is the best way to implement syntax highlighting of source code in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, syntax-highlighting, nstextview

I'm working on Cocoa Application that should be able to analyze and highlight a source code written in such languages as Objective-C, SQL, JavaScript, Python etc. The text should be editable too (by using NSTextView, for example).

Please advise what is the best way to implement such feature in Mac OS X 10.5.

There is no need to support auto-completion and other extra-features. Simple formatting by keywords, strings, #includes, and numbers but with cool performance is just OK.

Also, it would be great if configuration by languages were supported.

Thanks!

Comment: Intelligent syntax highlighting can be pretty hard - that's part of why Apple's doing so much work on the clang frontend to LLVM. You might want to check it out.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In preparing a project that will require something similar, I’ve found the following (but not evaluated them in depth):

- /Developer/Examples/OpenGL/Cocoa/GLSLEditorSample implements syntax highlighting.
- [IDEKit](http://projects.gandreas.com/idekit/), “an open-source framework that provides programmer source code editing, including syntax coloring, popup functions, and split frames”. This hasn’t been updated for a while (it touts 10.2 and 10.3 compatibility, and comes with a Project Builder project – can be converted with Xcode 2.5).
- [UKSyntaxColoredTextDocument](http://www.zathras.de/sourcecode.htm#UKSyntaxColoredTextDocument).

Comment: Gandreas killed the repo, but I salvaged a working copy (0.3, most recent) from an old SVN repo [here](https://github.com/CodaFi/IDEKit).  Mine has Xcode 4.x support, and ARC.

Answer (score 6):

I'd second Ahruman's advice - particulary looking at Uli's UKSyntaxColoredTextDocument as that will point you in the right direction as to which classes etc. you are going to have to learn about.

This is another excellent source of information:

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?ImplementSyntaxHighlighting

Good luck - Syntax highlighting is hard to get right, but lots of fun along the way!

Comment: Thank you guys. It definitely looks like the right answer. I'll explore Uli's component carefully, but I'd like to leave this question unanswered for some days.
Possibly, somebody will have come up with something new by this time.

Answer (score 3):

I had to look for a syntax highlighting solution for Cocoa recently and after searching on Stack Overflow, Google and GitHub couldn't find anything modern, easy to re-use and still in active development.

It seems most syntax highlighters these days are written for the web. Fortunately it's actually quite easy to embed them in a WebView to use in any Cocoa app. Communicating with the editor can be done through WebKit's [WebScriptObject protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebScriptObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Here's an example wrapper for the popular JavaScript text editor [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) for Cocoa:
https://github.com/swisspol/CodeMirrorView

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pygments, which is written in python, to generate an HTML representation of the source code, which can then be presented in a Web View.

(Note, as reflected in comment below - this answer was to the original question, which did not mention editable text.)

Comment: Thank you Matthew. Sorry, but I forgot to include one more requirement. Thе source code should be editable (placed in the NSTextView, for example). Is it possible to use Pygments to incorporate highlighting into NSTextView to achieve this goal?

Comment: I haven't done anything with pygments other than generate HTML, but I know it can mark up into other formats.  It may be that one of those can be a base for displaying the NSTextView.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using flex as described (in German) here [1]. You can find an example of this approach here [2].

[1] http://www.osxentwicklerforum.de/thread.php?postid=14764
[2] http://objectiveous.github.com/davenport/