# Syntax highlighting on iPhone Text-Editor

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I want to write a simple text editor for iPhone with syntax highlighting support for c,c++.
But the problem is, I dont't know how to do this. The first solution I was thinking about, was to go over the text and highlight keywords when the value of the UITextView has changed, but I think that if I got more than 1000lines of code that doesn't work very well.

Thanks for help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to implement syntax highlighting of source code in Cocoa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754591/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-syntax-highlighting-of-source-code-in-cocoa)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this answer [What is the best way to implement syntax highlighting of source code in Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754591/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-syntax-highlighting-of-source-code-in-cocoa/757301#757301) also there are some tutorials whnen you google "implementing syntax highlighting". Like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/SyntaxRichTextBox.aspx) one or [that](http://www.radupoenaru.com/implement-syntax-highlighting/) one.