# Set line height in UITextView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm already pretty sure that it can't be done with any public API, but I still want to ask:

**Is there any way to change the line height in a UITextView?**

Would be enough to do it statically, no need to change it at runtime. The problem is that the default line height is just WAY too small. Text will look extremely compressed and is a nightmare when trying to write longer texts.

thanks,
Max

**EDIT:** I know that there is `UIWebView` and that it's nice and can do styling etc. But it's *not editable*. I need a editable text component with acceptable line height. That thing from the Omni Frameworks doesn't help either, as it's too slow and doesn't feel right...

Answer (score 114, accepted):

After iOS 7, the styleString approach no longer works.

Two new alternatives are available.

Firstly, TextKit; a powerful new layout engine. To change line spacing, set the UITextView's layout manager's delegate:

```
textView.layoutManager.delegate = self; // you'll need to declare you implement the NSLayoutManagerDelegate protocol
```

Then override this delegate method:

```
- (CGFloat)layoutManager:(NSLayoutManager *)layoutManager lineSpacingAfterGlyphAtIndex:(NSUInteger)glyphIndex withProposedLineFragmentRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    return 20; // For really wide spacing; pick your own value
}
```

---

Secondly, iOS 7 now supports NSParagraphStyle's lineSpacing. This gives even more control, e.g. first line indentation, and calculation of a bounding rect. So alternatively...

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.headIndent = 15; // <--- indention if you need it
paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 15;

paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 7; // <--- magic line spacing here!

NSDictionary *attrsDictionary =
@{ NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle }; // <-- there are many more attrs, e.g NSFontAttributeName

self.textView.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello World over many lines!" attributes:attrsDictionary];
```

---

FWIW, the old contentInset method to align the text along the left edge of UITextView is also no use under iOS7. Instead, to remove the margin:

```
textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that you can't use it to make the line height *smaller*

Comment: how do you calculate the height of the text in textview then?

Comment: @TimWachter Have you tried to use negative values? Works for me.

Comment: @MichałZygar the second approach creates an NSAttributedString, which has methods to give you the required bounding rect.

Answer (score 25):

Note: this is not available in iOS7:

---

I have discovered that you can create a subclass that re-implements `[UITextView styleString]`:

```
@interface UITextView ()
- (id)styleString; // make compiler happy
@end

@interface MBTextView : UITextView
@end
@implementation MBTextView
- (id)styleString {
    return [[super styleString] stringByAppendingString:@"; line-height: 1.2em"];
}
@end
```

This is not private API usage: it is just subclassing. It's possible Apple may disagree of course (though considering how we all used to swizzle everything in order to customize UIKit appearance, I feel that this kind of “private” usage is not what Apple object to), but it's such an easy way to achieve the goals of this question that you may as well try it. Should the app be rejected you can spend the (probably significant) time on a more difficult solution.

Comment: Interesting grey-zone approach. ;)

Comment: It does not work, UIVIew doesn't seem to have any styleString

Comment: It works on `UITextView` not `UIView`. Tested with iOS 5 in an app I use everyday.

Comment: UITextView either doesn't appear to have any styleString. I'm getting UITextView for instance message doesn't declare a method with selector styleString

Comment: I just stuck a breakpoint in mine. Definitely getting called, previous call-stack frame is `[UITextView initWithFrame:]`. iOS 5.0.1.

Comment: I added the private category definition to the code sample, this will make it compile.

Comment: Does it pass throw review of Apple?

Comment: Does anyone know if this solution is App Store safe ?

Comment: It's safe, I have used it in one of my apps since version 1.0. Now I am at version 1.0.4 and all apps have passed the appstore review!

Comment: Is there a way to resize the cursor? The cursor is not vertically centered and way too tall when changing line height to a value much larger than the font size.

Comment: styleString is **not available** in iOS7

Comment: No longer works because `UITextView` is no longer backed by WebKit, but rather TextKit as of iOS 7.

Answer (score 21):

In the Attribute Inspector for the UITextView instead change the property `Text` to `Attributed` (from `Plain`), and click the `"more"` button, there you can set the line height and spacing.

[image: UITextView's Attribute Inspector]

Comment: Works! :) Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 19):

The only solution we've found and the one we've chosen: *create a custom font*. Sound silly but seems to be the only realistic way.

Comment: @ Max Seelemann: Have you ever found another solution to this problem or is this the only way? I guess FontLab will do and then simply resize font to base line and you'll have a better spacing, right? Thanks!

Comment: @n.evermind No we still use this solution. And as far as I can tell, iOS 5 will not change anything to that...

Comment: That's quite annoying. Do you thin coreText is an alternative? I just can't be bothered learning something new yet again... for something so simple (line spacing).

Comment: Well you *can* consider Core Text. But that has many more disadvantages, as I described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642540/uitextview-with-syntax-highlighting/3643425#3643425

Comment: Can u explain how to create custom font to change interline spacing?

Comment: You have to use a font editing software like [FontLab Studio](http://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/fontlab-studio/). As I didn't do the customization, I can't tell which exact tool we used and how to do it. HTH anyways.

Answer (score 10):

The UITextView subclass override of styleString only works if you define a category on UITextView that defines styleString, otherwise you get a compile error. For example, in your UITextView subclass:

```
#import "SomeDangTextView.h"

@interface UITextView ()

- (id)styleString;

@end

@implementation SomeDangTextView

- (id)styleString {
    return [[super styleString] stringByAppendingString:@"; line-height: 1.5em"];
}

@end
```

Comment: I tried Max Howell's answer before without success, dinked around in Apple's docs for awhile, and gave up. But this (defining a category on UITextView) is what got it to work. Thanks very much.

Comment: This worries me as a non-public (aka private) API. I dont see it documented: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html

Comment: This still isn't working for me.  How do you define -(id)styleString in the UITextView category?

Answer (score 5):

This question is almost 10 years old but this is how it's done:

Just implement the following method of `UITextViewDelegate` and set your attributes:

```
let textViewAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key:Any] = [
    .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .medium),
    .foregroundColor: UIColor.black,
    .paragraphStyle: {
        let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraph.lineSpacing = 4
        return paragraph
    }()
]

func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    textView.typingAttributes = textViewAttributes
}
```

It's important to add these attributes on `textViewDidBeginEditing` as the dictionary gets reset every time the text selection changes. More info can be found on the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview/1618629-typingattributes).

Comment: It doesn't seem to be necessary to do this as late as when the `textViewDidBeginEditing` delegate method is called. I'm setting `typingAttributes` right after instantiating the UITextView and getting the desired effect.

Answer (score -1):

According to Apple's Documentation you can use a UIWebView.

This class does not support multiple styles for text. The font, color, and text alignment attributes you specify always apply to the entire contents of the text view. To display more complex styling in your application, you need to use a UIWebView object and render your content using HTML.

Comment: It is if you intercept the tap on the WebView, show a UITextView on top, edit and save into the UIWebView ;)

Comment: right, but as the primary usage is while editing this still is not the best option. And there's another problem: It's very very hard (if at all possible) to manually place the insertion point in a UITextView upon an event. This, however, would be needed to switch views. :(

Comment: `UITextField` adopts `UITextInput` which includes `- (UITextPosition *)closestPositionToPoint:(CGPoint)point`, etc... sounds like what you need?

Answer (score -1):

This class does not support multiple styles for text. The font, color, and text alignment attributes you specify always apply to the entire contents of the text view. To display more complex styling in your application, you need to use a UIWebView object and render your content using HTML.

Comment: -1 That's not what the question was about. Plus it's also *stated* there that UIWebView is no choice since it does not offer editing.

Answer (score -4):

Use OHAttributedLabel Lib. This will solve all the problem you mentioned.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't. `OHAttributedLabel` is a UILabel -- a **noneditable** component. The question is about `UITextView` which is editable.