# Leading or Vertical distance between two lines in UITextView on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview

I want to set vertical linespacing between two lines in UITextView.

I searched a lot for the same but couldn't find any API or a way to go about it.

Although UIFont has ledding and lineHeight properties but they are readonly and hence doesn't solve the purpose.

Please let me know how to solve this problem

Comment: As a curiosity for readers: "Ledding" refers to the "ledd" (ie, the metallic substance, atomic number 82) which was used in early typesetting. It is pronounced "Led" as in Led Zeppelin, rather than "Leeed".  The older spelling "Led" (indeed exactly as in "led" zeppelin, which has the same meaning) is better and becoming more popular. It is very unfortunate when people pronounce it "leed" ... it's ledding (as in the metal).

Comment: It is however spelled "Leading" after the metal "Lead" ;-)

Comment: This is not ledding but its leading [Refer this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading)

Comment: Spelled "leading" after the metal "lead," and pronounced "ledding" like the metal "lead."

Comment: Lol Hi Roger .. I encourage you to ask some typesetters!  (Or I suppose, Jimmy Page ;-)  )

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at ["Set line height in UITextView"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760924/set-line-height-in-uitextview), it seems the only solution is to create a custom font.

Comment: I checked that but as mentioned in the comments by **Max Seelemann** on that page this view is not editable and hence doesn't solve my problem too.