# adjusting linespacing in UITextView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitextview

is there any way in iphone app that to adjust the linespacing between the lines in UITextview.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set line height in UITextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760924/set-line-height-in-uitextview)

Answer (score 0):

```
       NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
       paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 50.0f;
       paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = 50.0f;
       paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = 50.0f;
         NSString *string = @"if you want reduce or increase space between lines in uitextview ,you can do this with this,but donot set font on this paragraph , set this on uitextveiw.";

        NSDictionary *ats = @{
       NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle, 
         };

        [textview setFont:[uifont fontwithname:@"Arial" size:20.0f]];
        textview.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:ats];
```

Answer (score -1):

This works perfectly for me:

```
#define MAX_HEIGHT 2000     
CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]
              constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(100, MAX_HEIGHT)
                  lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

[textview setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
[textview setFrame:CGRectMake(45, 6, 100, size.height + 10)];
textview.text = text;
```

Comment: That doesn't actually answer the question that was asked.