# UiTextView - position when only one line is added

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

When 2 or more lines are added to my `UiTextView` it looks good but when the user enters just one line the text stays in the middle of the `UiTextView`. How can I force it to stay on the top left side of the `UiTextView` ?

Comment: Check this blog [iOS: Vertical aligning text in a UITextView](http://imagineric.ericd.net/2011/03/10/ios-vertical-aligning-text-in-a-uitextview/) or rather just set `contentOffset` to an appropriate value(zero or so).

Comment: have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760924/set-line-height-in-uitextview

Answer (score 1):

You can check this blog ([iOS: Vertical aligning text in a UITextView](http://imagineric.ericd.net/2011/03/10/ios-vertical-aligning-text-in-a-uitextview/)) which explains how to do center and bottom vertical alignment. Use similar logic and set contentOffset y param as zero in your case to make it top aligned.

This is the code from the blog,

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
   [textField addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:NULL];
   [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
   UITextView *tv = object;
   //Center vertical alignment
   //CGFloat topCorrect = ([tv bounds].size.height - [tv contentSize].height * [tv zoomScale])/2.0;
   //topCorrect = ( topCorrect < 0.0 ? 0.0 : topCorrect );
   //tv.contentOffset = (CGPoint){.x = 0, .y = -topCorrect};

   //Bottom vertical alignment
   CGFloat topCorrect = ([tv bounds].size.height - [tv contentSize].height);
    topCorrect = (topCorrect <0.0 ? 0.0 : topCorrect);
    tv.contentOffset = (CGPoint){.x = 0, .y = -topCorrect};
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I just found a much simpler solution. The next code will move just the text: `[textView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, 5,0)]`

Comment: But that is setting `contentInset` and it will set even if number of lines are more than 1 right? I think I misread your question then.

Comment: It will always force the text to stay in the upper right corner of the UITextView. That was the case when 2 lines were in but with one line the text was centered for some reason. `ContentInset` fixes that issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a much simpler solution. The next code will move just the text: `[textView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, 5,0)]`