# UITextView line height issue

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitextview, line

I try to set text in textview according to design. But the line height in design in more than default line height in UITextView, so I'm about to replace UITextView with the sequence of labels.

Is it possible to set line height in textview or interval between lines?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760924/set-line-height-in-uitextview

Comment: line height depend on font size of uitextview

Comment: Praveen S, your solution - is to use custom font. Does custom font include line height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way of setting line height to the `UITextView`  however you could create a custom textView and subclass it from UITextView and [re-implement `styleString` method for the `UITextView`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760924/set-line-height-in-uitextview)