# Lined UITextView in IOS7

Tags: ios, ipad, uitextview, ios7, uifont

I have a subclass of a UITextView (Custom Control DALinedTextView) where i draw lined text. It works perfect on iOS5 and iOS6 but on iOS7 it fails (text does not match lines).

```
   - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0f);

    if (self.horizontalLineColor)
    {
        CGContextBeginPath(context);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.horizontalLineColor.CGColor);

        // Create un-mutated floats outside of the for loop.
        // Reduces memory access.
        CGFloat baseOffset = 7.0f + self.font.descender;
        CGFloat screenScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
        CGFloat boundsX = self.bounds.origin.x;
        CGFloat boundsWidth = self.bounds.size.width;

        // Only draw lines that are visible on the screen.
        // (As opposed to throughout the entire view's contents)
        NSInteger firstVisibleLine = MAX(1, (self.contentOffset.y / self.font.lineHeight));
        NSInteger lastVisibleLine = ceilf((self.contentOffset.y + self.bounds.size.height) / self.font.lineHeight);
        for (NSInteger line = firstVisibleLine; line <= lastVisibleLine; ++line)
        {
            CGFloat linePointY = (baseOffset + (self.font.lineHeight * line));
            // Rounding the point to the nearest pixel.
            // Greatly reduces drawing time.
            CGFloat roundedLinePointY = roundf(linePointY * screenScale) / screenScale;
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, boundsX, roundedLinePointY);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, boundsWidth, roundedLinePointY);
        }
        CGContextClosePath(context);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }

    if (self.verticalLineColor)
    {
        CGContextBeginPath(context);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.verticalLineColor.CGColor);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, -1.0f, self.contentOffset.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, -1.0f, self.contentOffset.y + self.bounds.size.height);
        CGContextClosePath(context);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }
}
```

I know it's someting related to UIFont metrics..perphaps someone can help me out? I've change contentSize to intrinsicContentSize but it dos not work.

If i use systemFontOfSize it works perfectly, but with fontWithName it fails.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been struggling with this weird issue for quite a while, but finally stumbled upon a legit solution:

```
textView.layoutManager.usesFontLeading = NO;
```

This makes `UITextView` render text (almost) identically to `UILabel`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , i think you are using Custom Control `DALinedTextView`.

I am also facing a problem like you said in iOS7.
Even you can't scroll that control correctly in `iOS7`.

First i used that control and now i leaved it and using built-in `UITextView`. :D

Perhaps , you need to change the `font size` and `text margin` or `text padding` of your `textView`.

Comment: hey, but are you using lined uitextview? i've also done my own implementation and i cannot get it right, it only works with custom fonts (ttf) or with systemfont...

Comment: no bro. i am also using that DALinedTextView like you. it doesn't work in iOS7.

Comment: yes bro. i know it . however i use custom font. That's why i can't use this control. :D

Comment: if you find the solution, please let me know...otherwise i'll have to find .ttf files for all the fonts available on iOS..

Answer (score 0):

check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760924/set-line-height-in-uitextview).
It uses NSLayoutManagerDelegate, that is used in ios7.
For iOS 7, the styleString approach no longer works. 
You have to use NSLayoutManagerDelegate, it is easy to use.

```
txtViewNote.layoutManager.delegate = self;
txtViewNote.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"textView_bg_lines"]];

- (CGFloat)layoutManager:(NSLayoutManager *)layoutManager lineSpacingAfterGlyphAtIndex:(NSUInteger)glyphIndex withProposedLineFragmentRect:(CGRect)rect
{
return 20.5; // For really wide spacing
}
```

Comment: does not fix the problem... the line height is still wrong with fonts other than system font..

Comment: May be that is because you are drawing and i am using the image.

Comment: can you post an example of how you are doing it? and it works with all ios fonts?

Comment: can you post the image you're using, i cannot make it work.. also what uifont are you using?