# How can I make a UITextView layout text the same as a UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uitextview

I have a `UILabel` that I need to convert to a `UITextView` because reasons.  When I do this, the text is not positioned the same, despite using the same (custom) font.

I found that if I set:

```
textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

This gets the text very close, but if I superimpose the `UITextView` over top of the `UILabel`, I see the text positioning get farther apart with each new line.

[image: Screen shot showing text drift.]

The `UILabel` is green, the `UITextView` is black.  This is using `NSParagraphStyle` to set min and max line height to 15.

I've played with setting the paragraph style and min/max line height, but I haven't been able to match it exactly.  I'm not a printer, so I don't necessarily understand all of the font related terms in the documentation for `NSLayoutManager` and `NSTextContainer` and all that.

I only need to support iOS 7 and up.

I'm not going to switch to some crazy CoreText-based custom widget or use some random third party library.  I'm okay with close enough if I have to.  But it seems like there should be some combination of random properties to make them layout the same.

Comment: My font is HelveticaNeue 13, if that's helpful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I took the solution for line spacing found [at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760924/set-line-height-in-uitextview) and applied it to your issue. I managed to get it incredibly close by adjusting the `lineSpacing` property. I tested with HelveticaNeue size 13 and managed to get it to line up as shown in the screen shot below.

```
textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];

paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = -0.38;

NSDictionary *attrsDictionary =
@{ NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:13.0f],
 NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle};

textView.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textView.text attributes:attrsDictionary];
```

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Looks like workaround, but not a solution. It turns out, that boundingRectWithSize: for NSAttributedString returns size, that matches the size of how it is rendered by UITextView, but not UILabel. What if I need to use UILabel, but boundingRectWithSize's size doesn't correspond with it?

Comment: @user2327139 I agree that it is more of a workaround than a solution. Regarding your question, I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but if you have a new question, use the "Ask a Question" link. Include a link to this question if you think it would be helpful.

Comment: If you use attributed strings for both the UILabel and the UITextView, you can make the line spacing be the same in both. No hacks needed.

Answer (score 4):

I've been able to successfully 'impersonate' a *non-editable* multiline UILabel (as it happens, in a UITableViewCell subclass) with an equivalent *editable* multiline UITextView using the following :

```
_textView = UITextView.new;
_textView.font = _label.font;
_textView.textColor = _label.textColor;
_textView.textAlignment = _label.textAlignment;
_textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
_textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
_textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

and to make it behave well when doing actual edits, add the following to your UITextViewDelegate:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    ...
    [textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(textView.text.length, 0)];
    [textView scrollRectToVisible:[textView caretRectForPosition:textView.endOfDocument] animated:NO];
}
```