# Change color of NSAttributedString and open its link in safari

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

From server I get a string with html tag, it's like that:

```
  "It's a test - <a href=\"https://apple.com\" target=\"_blank\">Apple</a>""
```

I use this function to convert it to `NSAttributedString`.

```
  func convertHtmlTagsToString(text: String) {
      let attributedString = Data(text.utf8)      
      
      if let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: attributedString, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) {
         
         label.attributedText = attributedString
      }
   }
```

My first problem is I can't change the color of the label text, it's black, and my second problem is, how I can make the url part clickable that I can open safari with that link.

Thank you so much.

Comment: With a label you cannot unless you implement the logic by yourself. Use a `UITextView` with data detector instead.

Comment: Thanks, could you please tell me how to change its text color?

Comment: Ideally, using CSS. You are interpreting the data as HTML, therefore you can just wrap it into a `<style>` element.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55826193/swift-the-html-data-converted-to-nsattributed-string-doesnt-make-the-links-cli/