# Set NSAttributedString to UITextView

Tags: objective-c

I want to set `NSAttributedString` to `UITextView`; how do I go about doing that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITextView with Syntax Highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642540/uitextview-with-syntax-highlighting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at the [EGOTextView](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTextView) project on github. It discribes itself as a

> "A complete drop in replacement for UITextView, adding support for
> rich text editing."