# NSForegroundColorAttributeName undeclared

Tags: ios, ios4

When using the below snippet, i get the `undefined / undeclared error` on

> NSForegroundColorAttributeName

[This is the url i referred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482346/how-do-you-use-nsattributedstring)

my code snippet

```
NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.myDisplayTxt];
    [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,5)];
```

Please let me know

Comment: `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` is a part of Mac OSX Core Library. So can u please post some code to let all know how u have implemented.

Comment: @hpiOSCoder: Please help me out, i have included my code. thanks

Comment: Hey yes I'm on it. Actually, NSAttributedString Class reference doc says (in note inside square box) that for iOS u use CoreText framework. So i tried adding the framework, but didnt resolved the error. & at our tough luck the link u provided dont tell anything about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using kCTForegroundColorAttributeName.

Your code

```
NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.myDisplayTxt];
    [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,5)];
```

Make this change

```
[string addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName 
                value:(id)[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]
                range:NSMakeRange(0,5)];
```

From sample code by apple,

Add following after #import line to your .m file in which u use `addAttribute:`

```
#if (TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED || TARGET_OS_IPHONE)
#import <CoreText/CoreText.h>
#else
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#endif
```

Pls see if this helps. DONT FORGET TO ADD CORETEXT FRAMEWORK

Comment: still i get the same error NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.myDisplayTxt];
    [string addAttribute:kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,5)];

Comment: follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550739/set-nsattributedstring-to-uitextview

Comment: i get the below error  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString getCharacters:range:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x70c5430

Comment: for which line u r geting the error? Put some breakpoints & debug ur code to see where ur app is terminating

Comment: [self.myTextView setText:(NSString *)string];
in this line it crashes

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10491/discussion-between-user198725878-and-hp-ios-coder)

Comment: ok lets chat.. but before that have u seen link i commented previously?

Comment: Are you using an NSLog to display your NSMutableAttributedString?  I get the same error you do when I use NSLog.  The error goes away when I comment out the NSLog.

Answer (score 0):

what version of iOS are you targeting ?

NSForegroundColorAttributeName is a static NSString, declared in the iOS headers, but not part of your application, as is clearly specified in the headers it is available since iOS 6.0.