# Syntax Highlightable UITextView on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, nsattributedstring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UITextView with Syntax Highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642540/uitextview-with-syntax-highlighting)

I'm working on a source code editor for the iPad, but I'm stuck on square one: syntax highlighting. I'm planning on using libclang to do the heavy lifting, but there doesn't seem to be a good way to show rich text on iOS. I think the best solution would be to have a subclass of `UITextView` that supports `NSAttributedString` drawing, but I'm not sure how to do that. I've seen things like Omni's text editor, but it doesn't look very good. I only need multiple colors of a monospaced font. Is there a framework or library that would help draw attributed strings in a `UITextView` subclass?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Really?  Google the title of your question. possible duplicate of [UITextView with Syntax Highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642540/uitextview-with-syntax-highlighting) and [set nsattributedstring to uitextview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550739/set-nsattributedstring-to-uitextview)

Comment: @CodaFi Sorry. I was looking for something along the lines of EGOTextView which is linked to in one of those questions, but I guess I never found it. I asked again because nothing seemed recent and I was wondering if something open source had come since those posts. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cocoanetics.com/parts/dtrichtexteditor/ is a paid solution that would do almost all the work for you.

https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText is the open source backend for just the text highlighting.