# iOS Set text range in textview UIColor

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4

I am looking for all the text in my text view to be gray and then the first sentence to be black. How do I set that range to black. I already have the first sentence string/range. Thank You.

```
    [tv setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

    id<UITextInputTokenizer> tokenizer = tv.tokenizer;
    UITextRange *range = [tokenizer rangeEnclosingPosition:tv.beginningOfDocument
                                           withGranularity:UITextGranularitySentence
                                               inDirection:UITextStorageDirectionForward];
    NSString *firstSentence = [tv textInRange:range];
    NSLog(@"%@",firstSentence);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not much good news to offer here.  You want an NSAttributed string, but that's not available as the model of the standard text view.  I haven't checked this out personally, but there's some web code that might help referenced [here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550739/set-nsattributedstring-to-uitextview)

Comment: could i make a custom font that has a color?

Comment: can i put a cgrect around it? If so how would i go about this.

Comment: i think i see what you're thinking - put a view in front of the text and use that to alter the color? the hitch is that there's no predicting how some arbitrary text will get word-wrapped.  the only method you have available is NSString sizeWithFont:.  If you knew, say, that the sentence was always at the start of the text view, then you could add a subview to the text view at roughly 0,0 and size it with the sizeWithFont:.  Then set it's background color.  But it's not very general.  Kind of stinks that iOS doesn't give us a text view with rich text control.

Comment: about your first question - you can set the textColor for the view, but it will apply to all of the text in the view.