# Changing the font style in textView?

Tags: xcode, textview, font-size

How can I change the font style of the header text to **bold** or *italic* in textView in Xcode?

Also, how can I do this for only some of the words in textView?

Comment: What’s your target platform: Mac OS X or iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short you can't do that in `UITextView` right now. If there is no user interaction, consider `UIWebView`. Actually, you should just read [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642540/uitextview-with-syntax-highlighting).

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the second queston:"how can I do this for only some of the words in textView?"

You can change "Text" from plain to attributed in the attribute inspector. with a right click you can change a selected word in bold or italic etc.