# How to activate spellchecking for a contentEditable div in a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

UIWebView (iOS 5.0) does not show the red-squiggly spelling correction underlines for this:

```
id html= @"<div spellcheck=\"true\" contenteditable=\"true\"></div>"
[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

Is it possible to get them?

Comment: what things do you expect to be spell checked?  the entire contents of the HTML file or just the editable text fields or?

Comment: The entire `contenteditable` div. The HTML 5 spec says the markup above should work. But it doesn't.

Comment: Do you require spell check (autocorrect) for any textfield entry in text box, which is available on html page? Am I getting you correctly? If is it so, then might be ans given below will be helpful to you.

Comment: @MaxHowell have yo figured this out yet?

Answer (score 1):

There are some HTML tag properties available by [Apple Safari Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008058-SW2)

> **autocomplete**:
>   If off, deactivates automatic completion for an input element; If on, activates automatic completion for the element.
>   Related Tags
>           “input”
>   Availability
>   Available in Safari 1.0 and later. Available in iOS 1.1.1 and later.
>
> **autocorrect**: If off, deactivates automatic correction for a form or input element; If on, activates automatic correction for the element.
>   Availability Available in iOS 1.1.1 and later.

Hope this might be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work. I now have: `<div spellcheck="true" autocomplete="on" autocorrect="on" contenteditable="true"></div>`. I also tried changing the tag to `form` and `input` in case that helped.

Comment: According to the linked Safari Guidelines, `autocomplete` and `autocorrect` only work on input and form tags (such as: `<input type="text" name="key" autocomplete="on">`).  They work in that regard, as they control autocompletion and autocorrection.  There is currently no 'spellcheck' option supported by webkit, as per the link you provided.