# Underlining text in UITextView: Overriding drawRect isn't enough?

Tags: ios

I am trying to underline some words of the text in an UITextView.

The normal approach would be to override drawRect, bit it seems that there's another method being called to actually draw the text when typing, and drawRect is instead only used when the view is moved or resized.

What else should I override?

Best regards,
  Anders

Comment: Maybe `drawTextInRect:`, but i am not sure.

Comment: @RomanTemchenko `drawTextInRect:` is defined for `UITextField` and `UILabel` only, alas.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITextView with Syntax Highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642540/uitextview-with-syntax-highlighting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime the text in the UITextView gets updated you could call [textView setNeedsDisplay], which would cause drawRect: to be called at some point in the near future.