# How to input Multiple color text in UiTextView?

Tags: iphone, ios, textbox, uitextview

I needed UITextView where user can enter text in multiple color at the time of inserting. For example if he enter XYZ, then color will be red, if he enter ABC then it must be blue.

Comment: plz send some code lines to get your issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This answer was given prior the release of iOS 6 and the support of NSAttributedString in UITextViews.**

Sorry this is not possible a UITextView is plain text only. You can only set text and font attributes globally applying to the whole text.

Have a look at [UITextView with Syntax Highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642540/uitextview-with-syntax-highlighting), it's related to your situation. The first answer gives you a good overview and some suggestions how to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Nick for you help. I solved it. Please have a look on https://github.com/enormego/EGOTextView

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this helps, as of IOS 6, you can now change the attributes which technically includes Fonts, and Colors. I was successful with Fonts change for part of the text, but seeing a challenge in changing the colour, anyhow, below is the way to go in case Apple is applying a change to this someday since AttributedText is a property of UITextView and should allow the same standards.

You can use (NSMutableAttributedString) as opposed to (NSString) in connection with .attributedText (as opposed to .text), see the example below, it's very doable, just create a new UITextView and then make do the delegate etc name it txtLog as per below:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *Temp = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Heider Sati... Hello World"];

[Temp addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:30.0f] range:NSMakeRange(0, 11)]; /* This will change the first 11 characters into the font above... */

[Temp addAttribute:NSStrokeColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(12, 15)]; /* This will change the color on the other characters starting from 12 to 15... */


txtLog.attributedText = Temp;
```

You can also use NSAttributedString instead of NSMutableAttributedString if you like, but I use the Mutable to append the string if needed, as it's mostly the case when you read and write into the UITextView field.

I hope this helps,

Kind Regards
Heider Sati

Comment: getting crash while using your code. "out of bound". and `NSStrokeColorAttributeName` is also not working for me I use `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` instead of  `NSStrokeColorAttributeName`

Answer (score 0):

Usual UITextView does not allow to have text in multiple color. You should implement your own UITextView

Comment: Thanks George, Please have a look on http://github.com/enormego/EGOTextView. It is doing the same.