# Programming multiline mixed uiview types text

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, comments, uilabel

How would I elegantly achieve multiline text that includes a combination of links, plain text, and formatted words? Right now, all I can think of is breaking each word into a token and displaying/positioning it differently (UILabel, UIButton, etc), however, this is terribly inefficient. Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve from the comments feature in Instagram.

[image: Instagram comments]

Notice, formatted link to user name, indented multiline text, and possibility of inline links to hashtags.

Comment: I'm looking to the answer to this question myself and so far the most helpful thing I can find is this - <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642540/uitextview-with-syntax-highlighting> but I'm wondering if this is the most recent/relevant answer. Good Luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit Sep 14**

So I was able to implement something very similar using [FTCoreTextView](https://github.com/FuerteInternational/FTCoreText)
It was simple to import/implement. I am using the code as a static library in my ARC project.

The following are the core components:

- I use a method to set the style for my cell's `FTCoreTextView`

  ```
   (NSArray *)getCoreTextStyle{
      NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];

      FTCoreTextStyle *defaultStyle = [FTCoreTextStyle new];
     defaultStyle.name = FTCoreTextTagDefault;    //though the default name is already set to FTCoreTextTagDefault
     defaultStyle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:14.f];
     defaultStyle.textAlignment = FTCoreTextAlignementLeft;
     [result addObject:defaultStyle];


         FTCoreTextStyle *linkStyle = [defaultStyle copy];
     linkStyle.name = FTCoreTextTagLink;
     linkStyle.color = [UIColor blueColor];//[del colorWithHexString:@"3aa98"];
         linkStyle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:14.f];
      [result addObject:linkStyle];

          return  result;
   }
  ```
- Then in your cell you would set the text for the view, assign a delegate, etc. (My `FTCoreTextView` overrides a plain `IBOutlet` for a `UIView`)

  ```
  [myFTTView setDelegate:self];
  [myFTTView addStyles:[self getCoreTextStyle]];
  [myFTTView setText:[self parseLinks:text]];
  [myFTTView setNeedsDisplay];
  ```
- Parse links is a method i separately define to search for hashtags and usernames and then set a style when they are found (this code is rough and leaves much to be improved. I am considering switching to [CoreTextHyperlink](https://github.com/jasarien/CoreTextHyperlinkView) which already has code search for hashtags and @usernames.)

  ```
  -(NSString *) parseLinks: (NSString *)cap{
     NSArray *split = [cap componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
     NSMutableArray *words = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:split];

        for (NSString *word in split){

           if([word hasPrefix:@"#"] || [word hasPrefix:@"@"]){

              NSString *reformat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@|%@%@", hashlink,word, word, endhashlink];
              [words replaceObjectAtIndex:[split indexOfObject:word] withObject:reformat];
          }

      }
      return [words componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
  }
  ```
- Last but not least, the method called after a tag/username is clicked

  ```
  - (void)coreTextView:(FTCoreTextView *)acoreTextView receivedTouchOnData:(NSDictionary *)data {

      NSString *key = [data objectForKey:@"url"];
      if([key hasPrefix:@"#"]){
         //do something for tag
      }
     else{
        //do something for user.
     }

     return;

     }
  ```

Comment: i used FTcoretextView , and having a problem with it .. i want to get the height of coreTextview's text dynamically  (which i added as a uiview in my storyboard tableview cell), when i try to access coreTextView (UIview in cell ) in heightForRowAtIndexPath : app crashes due to EXC bad access .. can you help me in how to get height of text view

Answer (score 1):

Two ways I can think of:

- use CoreText with `NSAttributedString`s. Difficult to achieve, especially for the links (you'll have to register a listener somewhere, compute on which "link" you "clicked", ...), but provides the best performance.
- use a `UIWebView` and write the HTML on-the-fly. Less performant, but much more flexible.