# Putting Multi colored text in UITextView/UIlabel and calculating height dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I need to add a long string to a UiTextView/UiLabel or any UI Element. Parts of this string are of different colors. Also, i need to find out what will be the height of this element after setting this attributed string on it, given i hcan work out a fixed width. I know i can use boundingRectWithSize:, but how do i create dictionary, as there are more than one NSForegroundColorAttributeName values. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please refer link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642540/uitextview-with-syntax-highlighting

Comment: It does not talk about dynamic height calculation.

Comment: I don't understand why changing colore(`NSForeGroundColorAttributeName`) should change the size of the rendered text.

Comment: If it does not, then how to calculate the dynamic height for appended product of different attributed texts with different colors and fonts.

Comment: This link is for multicolour textview text...